# Css centering weird behavior

Tags: css, css-position, inline, centering, absolute

I am trying to center form on the screen. I am using absolute element with left and top set on 50% and move it back to center by css transform. So far so good, but when I increase left to 90% form elements go under. I would expect that they just move outside of view port.

```
.center {
  padding: 30px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 90%;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

Here is the effect I don't [understand](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/RWdNLe/)

If someone can explain me why those element go under each other? Even if they are inside absolute element.
To add more wierdness, if the 'left' value will be negative, elements just go out side view port?
I know that

```
white-space:nowrap;
```

will do the trick, but WHY?

Thanks in advance

Comment: They're not wrapping for me...

Comment: Ok You right, wrong word :)

Comment: It happens because the browser tries to size the form so that it fits in the viewport (*due to lack of a width value for the form*). This causes the form to decrease in width and so the elements (*that are `inline-block`*) *go under* as you say.

Comment: Is this behavior describe in css3 spec, or is it just  browser thing?

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out in the comments, this behavior is related to `inline-block` level elements, but it also has to do with your `position: absolute;` rule, regarding your specific situation.

As you can see in the **[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/jvLq3ae1/)** when `inline-block` level elements start reaching the outside boundaries of the viewport, the will `wrap` or `collapse`; this has to do with the nature of the `display` property.

There are a few ways to combat this:

- As you mentioned `white-space: nowrap` is one
- As Gaby alluded to in his comment, giving the element a `width` value will correct this as well - **[DEMO](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/qOvdyG)**
- Changing your `position` to `relative` will also fix this - **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/jvLq3ae1/1/)**

The actual reason you are experiencing this issue is because your `.center` element *which **does** have* `display: block`, is losing it's inherit `width: 100%` because it has `position: absolute;` or alternatively put, losing it's status as a `block` level element.